# IE 10-11 не видит условные комментарии

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, if

Подключаю в хедере

```
 <!--[if IE]>
        <style>
.headerbg{
background: #000;
height: 150px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
        </style> 
    <![endif]-->
```

IE8 видит нормально и меняет фон головы, а вот IE11 и 10 не воспринимают эту систему,почему и как это исправить, на всякий

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> A page using Conditional Comments
> worked as intended in Windows Internet
> Explorer 9, but no longer works in
> Internet Explorer 10.

Answer (score 2):

Поддержка условных комментариев в стандартном режиме и режиме совместимости Internet Explorer 10 была удалена для улучшения взаимодействия и совместимости с HTML5. Это означает, что условные комментарии теперь обрабатываются как обычные комментарии, так же как в других браузерах. Это изменение может повлиять на страницы, написанные специально для Windows Internet Explorer, или страницы, использующие определитель браузера и подстраивающиеся под Internet Explorer.

Страница, использующая условные комментарии, работает нормально в Windows Internet Explorer 9, но не работает в Internet Explorer 10.

Используйте css хак:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   /* стили только для IE10 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, спасибо для 10 и 11 версии подключается так

```
<![if IE]>Вы используйете IE<![endif]>
```