# как закрасить кнопку select в нужный цвет

Tags: css

[image]

Как закрасить кнопку select в нужный цвет. Белая стрелка на сером фоне. С border понятно

Comment: это что-то кастомное. например span, стилизованный в CSS и размещенный поверх

Comment: Селект не стилизуется, нужно имитировать его.

Comment: Кому интересно - ответ [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/73440/) На чистом CSS

Comment: если много где используется, то я бы поставил formstyler и особо не переживал

Answer (score 5):

## Быстрый ответ

```css
select {
  border: 2px solid #5B5B5B;
  background: transparent;
  width: 125px;
  padding: 5px 35px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 28px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: no-repeat right url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAZCAMAAAAVHr4VAAAASFBMVEVbW1v+/v7Y2NiDg4P7+/vj4+PV1dV0dHRiYmJeXl729vby8vLr6+vPz8/CwsK8vLytra2pqamYmJiVlZWHh4d2dnZpaWloaGivQPliAAAAVklEQVQoz93PSQ6AIBBE0WIScJ69/03VdCQGGvfyt29ThQJT8pWKtRIh42O0OuCKpPGxDmnekOmN3UQ4gK2/rd55PJoLJ2SahWgdK3R2QTYr8ZHDbzsBMLkBiiUpVMwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=')
}


/* CAUTION: IE hackery ahead */

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
  /* remove default arrow on ie10 and ie11 */
}


/* target Internet Explorer 9 to undo the custom arrow */

@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
  select {
    background: none\9;
    padding: 5px\9;
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>5 кг</option>
    <option selected>10 кг</option>
    <option>20 кг</option>
    <option>30 кг</option>
</select>
```

Здесь использовалось решение #1, описанное ниже

## Описание решений

На stackoverflow.com пользователем Danield предложено [3 решения для стилизации `select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968900/3287100).

*Я позволил себе сделать вольный перевод данного ответа, сохранив все ссылки на статьи и примеры из оригинального ответа.*

## Решение #1 - `appearance: none`

[Демо](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/bgJOyV?editors=1100)

Суть решения заключается в том, чтобы спрятать стрелочку с помощью `appearance: none` и добавить произвольное изображение.

```
select {
   -webkit-appearance: none; 
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;       /* удаляем стандартную стрелочку */
   background-image: url(...);   /* добовляем произвольное изображение */
}
```

`appearance: none` имеет [хорошую поддержку браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance), однако не поддерживается IE11- и Firefox 34-

Мы можем добавить поддержку IE10 и IE11 добавив

```
select::-ms-expand { 
    display: none; /* скрывает стрелку в IE10 и IE11 */
}
```

К сожалению, мы не сможем скрыть стрелку в IE9, мы лишь можем убрать нашу собственную и оставить стандартную

```
/* target Internet Explorer 9 to undo the custom arrow */
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    select {
        background-image:none\9;
        padding: 5px\9;
    } 
}
```

Если нужна поддержка IE9- и Firefox 34-, тогда:

## Решение 2 - Обрезать элемент `select`, чтобы спрятать стрелочку

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/YvCHW/4246/)

Суть решения заключается в том, чтобы обернуть `select` элементом `div`, который имеет фиксированную ширину и `overflow:hidden`. Элементу `select` установить ширину на примерно `20px` больше чем ширина `div`. В результате стандартная стрелка будет не видна, будет обрезана элементом `div`, и мы можем использовать любое фоновое изображение в правой части `div`.

**Преимущество** этого решения в широкой поддержке браузерами (IE8+, браузеры на WebKit и Gecko). Однако, есть и **недостаток**, выпадающий список с `option` выступает относительно правого края `select` на те самые `20px`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее о способе можно прочитать [тут](https://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)

Если стандартная стрелочка необхоима на Firefox 34-, но вам не нужна поддержка старых IE, тогда:

## Решение 3 - `pointer-events`

Идея заключается в том, чтобы перекрыть стандартную стрелку `select` элементом с `pointer-events:none`.

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sNwrs/2101/)

**Преимущество**: хорошо выглядит и работает на WebKit и Gecko.
**Недостаток**: вы не можите добавить `:hover` или `cursor:pointer` своей стрелочке, так как мы отключили события курсора. Еще один недостаток, Internet Explorer 10 и ниже [не поддерживает](https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events) `pointer-events`, это означает, что клик по элементу со своей стрелочкой не приведет к открытию списка.

Можно использовать [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) или [условные комментарии](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii), чтобы вернуть стандартные стрелочки в IE.

Учтите, что IE10 больше [не поддерживает условные комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326952/ie-10-11-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8). Однако, есть еще один способ отключить `pointer-events` для IE10 с помощью [CSS hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916454/3287100).

Подробнее о способе можно прочитать [тут](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/custom-select-drop-downs-with-css3/)

Comment: Если вы считаете этот ответ полезным, то прошу поблагодарить автора [оригинального ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968900/3287100)

Comment: В переводах ссылку на источник лучше в сам вопрос добавить. а, это я проглядел ссылку в ответе