# Кастомизация select

Tags: javascript, css

Какой самый адекватный и нормальный способ кастомизации select без подключение сторонних библиотек?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Руками написать код - самый адекватный способ

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669603/196740. Может, натолкнет на решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Может select и получится стилизовать, но вот его "option" с помощью обычного css - нет

Comment: это плагин https://github.com/Dimox/jQueryFormStyler  , это результат : https://www.dropbox.com/s/iz9q083oh4bgww6/stack.png