# Почему не работают условные комментарии?

Tags: html, css

Есть, собственно, вот такое и оно не работает
Хотя должно
  Думал, что я налажал-но даже ворованный код не работает

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Хаки и внутренние комментарии</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        DIV {
           color:aqua;
        }
    </style>
    <!--Тут творится некрофилия-->
      <!--[if IE]>
          <style type="text/css">
          DIV {
color:red;
          }
    </style>
           <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!--Нифига не красный-->
<div>А в ie этот текст красный</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В каком IE? . .

Comment: Ответ где-то тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/326952/186083

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что ie 10 - 11 не поддерживают условные комментарии.

Есть такой хак

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   /* стили только для IE10 IE11 */
}
```